# C# enums type conversion

Tags: c#, enums, casting

I have got a variable in Appsettings namely,

```
_tablename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Tablename");
```

I have to convert the variable _tablename to a specific enum type. I understand that we cannot use constructors in C# enums.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your enum look like? Also, what is the `_tablename` value?

Comment: [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: What is the type of _tablename? If it's an int then you can just cast it to the enum you wish, provided its value matches one of the enum's values. Or you can try Enum.TryParse, as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-parse

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum PetType
    {
    None,
    Cat = 1,
    Dog = 2
    }

    static void Main()
    {
    // A.
    // Possible user input:
    string value = "Dog";

    // B.
    // Try to convert the string to an enum:
    PetType pet = (PetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PetType), value);

    // C.
    // See if the conversion succeeded:
    if (pet == PetType.Dog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Equals dog.");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse.  For example, if you have an enum `Color`:

```
enum Color
{
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Green
}
```

You could use `TryParse` like this:

```
Color myColor;

if (Enum.TryParse<Color>("Red", out myColor))
{
    // successfully parsed.
}
```